# colData design issues, need help in R

Tags: r, differential-equations, bioconductor

Hej, im a microbiologist working in my master and I accidently blurted out I took basic bioinformatic as a course and now wants some help with some 39k data entries (my terminology is not the greatest)

Im working on a larger dataset
the count matrix looks like this

```
genes |A.1|A.2|A.3|A.4|B.1|B.2|B.3|B.4|C.1|C.2|C.3|C.4|D.1|D.2|D.3|D.4
AT5G   *imagine a bunch of numbers here  
AT6G
AT7G
AT8G
AT9G
```

I got the count matrix down, but im having issues with the colData design

My professor wants it so the DESeq() is comparing A2 (its a timepoint) to B2 but I cannot for the life of me get it to work

This is my ColData

```
coldata <- data.frame(sample = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4),rep("D", 4)),
                     timestamp = c(rep("1",1),rep("2",1),rep("3",1),rep("4",1)))
```

which looks like this

```
sample   timestamp
<chr>    <chr>
A   1           
A   2           
A   3           
A   4           
B       1
B       2           
B       3       
B       4       
C       1           
C       2
C       3           
C       4       
D   1       
D   2   
D   3   
D   4
```

and this is my

DESeqDataSetFromMatrix

```
dds_sub <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = count_matrix, colData = coldata, design = ~ sample + timestamp)
```

as you can se in my resultnames(dds.sub)

```
resultsNames(dds_sub)
[1] "Intercept"                              "sample_dcp5_vs_Col.0"                  
[3] "sample_pat1.path1.path2.summ2_vs_Col.0" "sample_summ2_vs_Col.0"                 
[5] "timestamp_CIM_24hr_vs__NT_0min"         "timestamp_CIM_45min_vs__NT_0min"       
[7] "timestamp_CIM_6d_vs__NT_0min"
```

I only get options for sample or for timestamp

what I need is sample AND timestamp specifically

```
sample_A.2_VS_B.2
```

but R keeps spitting this error after me

```
Error in cleanContrast(object, contrast, expanded = isExpanded, listValues = listValues, :A 2 and B 2 should be levels of sample such that sample_A.2_vs_A and sample_B.2_vs_A are contained in 'resultsNames(object)'
```

I could really use some help

Comment: perhaps it is better to ask this question on the Bioconductor suppoort site https://support.bioconductor.org

Comment: Ohhh they so have a support page  thanks I'll check it out!